# Smoothness of an algebraic subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

Is every subvariety of a smooth algebraic variety a smooth variety ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you thought of any examples (e.g. plane curves)?

Comment: @loch : I think of the following example : $ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y^2 = x^3 \ \} \subset \mathbb{A}^2 ( \mathbb{R} ) $ , so $ \mathbb{A}^2 ( \mathbb{R} ) $ is smooth but $ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y^2 = x^3 \ \} $ isn't smooth, right ?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: @loch : Thank you.  ;-)